# Android and Firestore

Tags: android, firestore

Используется ли совместно с Firestore локальная база данных?

Я знаю, что Firestore кэширует активно используемые данные и можно без проблем получить данные в offline, но, также знаю, что Transaction фэйлится в офлайне.

Тогда ситуация: "read to db, write to db, write to db" - тут будет transaction и она может зафэйлится в офлайне.

Что делать в такой ситуации? 
Использовать локальную или может есть другой подход?

Прошу прощения за некоторую сумбурность.

Comment: я бы не сказал, что firebase нормально кэширует данные и может использовать их оффлайн.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Тогда ситуация: "read to db, write to db, write to db" - тут будет transaction и она может зафэйлится в офлайне.

Транзакции нужны для выполнения **неделимых** функций. Когда вам нужно изменить **значение, доступ к которому имеют многие** (как с банкосвким счётом, счёт один, списаний может быть много).

По опыту: запущенная транзакция пытается выполниться несколько раз, после чего фейлится. Чем сложнее транзакция, тем выше вероятность, что она сфейлится. Помните, что

> Transactions are not persisted across app restarts

В оффлайне так и так ничего работать не будет, но вы можете кешировать данные для отображения ([Querying Data Offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!